# How redirect if change url php

Tags: php, html

I have the URL:

```
http://localhost/downoald.php?file=M85sAGZfHDfAD5ff
```

I want do if user delete

```
?file=M85sAGZfHDfAD5ff
```

Redirect in index page

Comment: check if you have value in file variable if not redirect the user to index.php

Comment: Just do something like, `if (empty($_GET['file'])) header("Location: index.php");`. Change empty to !isset if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.htaccess` you could achieve that with the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(file=)?$
RewriteRule ^downoald.php$ / [R=302,NC,L]
```

With PHP you could do it from your code, for example:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['file']) || empty($_GET['file']))
{
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}

// rest of your code
```